# Azure search service's performance is different for Production and staging environment

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have used search service with pricing tier 'basic' and single search service for both Production and staging environment. But I observed performance difference in both the environment. On Production when it takes 93ms on staging it takes 1673ms. could you please help me with the reason why it is happening. Is azure assigns any priority to Production than staging?

Comment: Your Question Is Not Match https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have to be more specific in your question: what request are you talking about? What are the service names? In general, individual requests can have very different latency, even on the same service. To compare performance, you need to aggregate a large number of requests over a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the VMs used in Production environment have far superior configuration than the ones used in Staging. This is probably why you are observing a degraded performance in Staging env.

Try to bump up the configs of your Staging VMs and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the staging VM is different from the production, which should is theoretically a mistake. The two machines should be 100% identical.

However, the validity of your results is greatly dependant on the way you measure the query time, please provide additional information. If, for example, you set a stopwatch timer that starts and ends right before and after the query is done, then you effective time also includes data transfer time, therefore if the bandwidth on staging is not on par with production you should see great differences.